# FileNotFoundException for a file I know is in the directory

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

In the following program I am trying to read from the Hw1_1.java source code. I get a FileNotFoundException every time (probably for a good reason). I know the program isn't complete as I am just trying to stop getting the exception. I am at a loss.

If someone could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

```
package hw1_1;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hw1_1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of a java source code file");

        String inputFileName = console.next();
        String outputFileName = (inputFileName + ".txt");

        try {

            File inputFile = new File(inputFileName);
            Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputFileName);

            while ( in .hasNextLine()) {
                String line = console.nextLine();
                out.println(line);
            }

            in .close();
            out.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
            System.out.println("File Not Found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running from an IDE? If so, you might be running from an unexpected location. Try using an absolute path to the file

Comment: Perhaps: `String line = console.nextLine();` should be: `String line = in.nextLine();`

Comment: Clearly the file is not located where the Java program is looking for it.  Try printing out the value of `System.getProperty("user.dir")` to see the current directory.  Also, print out the filename to ensure that you are looking for what you think you are looking for.  Or better, step through the code in and IDE debugger.

Comment: You can also print out the value of `inputFile.getAbsolutePath()` to verify that you are looking for the correct file

Comment: Make sure the line `File inputFile = new File(inputFileName)` has correct filepath in inputFileName along with the file extension.

Comment: Right click on file and in properties , you could find the original file path, just paste that one in console with filename

Answer (score 0):

It's really a good idea - to first check the user directory of your java program. Once you know, you can easily debug the FileNotFoundException issue.

You can simply print the user directory from following code.

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir")) ;
```

Using absolute path for the file is another way of solving problem, but that's a little irregular way of doing.

Answer (score -1):

You need to be aware of path complexity in your code, especially if you are using IDE as IDE can have a different execution path

Based on your code, if the value `inputFileName` is just the file name (let's say *log.txt*) and the execution path is actually different, then your code will never find the path

The quickest and dirty solution to quickly prove this is to use the full absolute path as the value of `inputFileName` for example:

```
String inputFileName = "/var/tmp/log.txt"
```

or

```
String inputFileName = "C:/workspace/temp/log.txt"
```

Once this verifies that your code can read the file, then you can start handling the path issue, good luck.